# Structure like priority queue but with something like lower bound

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue, lower-bound

I want a structure to store (for example) numbers where I can insert and remove elements, my structure remains sorted always (like a priority queue) BUT with the possibility of knowing where is a given number, and every operation in logarithmic time.

Maybe with lower_bound, upper_bound, or just a binary search, but in priority_queue what blocks me to do binary search is that I cannot access the elements with an index, only the first one.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking, but how about std::set?

Comment: with set I cannot know where is an element in logarithmic time. I can get a pointer pointing to an element with lower_bound for example but then to know its position I need distance between pointer which is linear

Comment: It sounds like a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) is what you're looking for. Also, it is possible to have an indexed heap that will give you O(1) access to arbitrary items.

Comment: I don’t see the problem with a set (or a map, or a multiset or a multimap). The key must be unique so you will find any item in logarithm time. If you have duplicate keys, either you should include multiple fields in the key, or take the first item or have relatively few duplicates in which case it does matters much if you have to check a few extra items. If you need to find items some other way, then you might have extra containers and keep them in synch by putting everything in a __manager__ class so that a single class is responsible to ensure everything stay coherent.

Comment: Also linear search is not so bad for simple comparison of small number of items. Often, there is some extra overhead for other containers so you must prifile your performance to see if it is really a problem or you are doing premature optimisation.

Comment: Hi Jim Mischel, the idea of the skip list is indeed what I need, but that has linear worst-case complexity, so as some things are randomly assigned I can't guarantee the time to be small.

Comment: @seba If you read the original skip list paper (linked from the Wikipedia article) and other research done on the data structure, it's virtually impossible to build a degenerate structure. Well, unless your random number generator is broken. I've used skip list quite a lot to hold hundreds of millions of items, and I've never had a performance problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’re looking for an [order statistics tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), an augmented BST that supports all the regular BST operations in time O(log n), along with two others:

- rank(elem): return which index elem would occupy in the sorted sequence.
- index(k): given an index k, return the element at that index in the sorted sequence.

The two above operations run in O(log n) time, making them extremely fast.

You can treat an order statistics tree as a priority queue. Insertions work as normal BST insertions, and to extract the lowest/highest element you just remove the smallest/greatest element from the tree, which you can do in time O(log n) by just walking down the left or right spines of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

A priority queue does not keep things in sorted order. At least, not typically. A priority queue makes it possible for you to quickly obtain the next item in the sequence. But you can't efficiently access, say, the 5th item in the queue.

I know of three different ways to build a priority queue in which you can efficiently access items by key:

- Use a balanced binary search tree to implement the queue. Although all operations are O(log n), typical running time is slower than a binary heap.
- Implement the heap priority queue as a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). This is a good option. I've seen some people report that a skip list priority queue outperforms a binary heap. A search for [C++ skip list] will return you lots of implementations.
- What I call an indexed binary heap also works. Basically, you marry a hash map or dictionary with a binary heap. The map is indexed by key, and its value contains the index of the item in the heap array. Such a thing is not difficult to build, and is quite effective.
- Come to think of it, you can make an indexed version of any type of heap.

You have a number of options. I rather like the skip list, myself, but your mileage may vary.

The indexed binary heap, as I pointed out, is a hybrid data structure that maintains a dictionary (hash map) and a binary heap. Briefly how it works:

The dictionary key is the field that you use to look up an item that you put into the heap. The value is an integer: the index of that item in the heap.

The heap itself is a standard binary heap implemented in an array. The only difference is that every time you move an item from one place to another in the heap, you update its location in the dictionary. So, for example, if you swap two items, you have to swap not only the items themselves in the array, but also their positions as stored in the dictionary. For example:

```
heap is an array of string references
dict is a dictionary, keyed by string

swap (a, b)
{
    // swap item at heap[a] with item at heap[b]
    temp = heap[a]
    heap[a] = heap[b]
    heap[b] = temp
    // update their positions in the dictionary
    dict[heap[a]] = b
    dict[heap[b]] = a
}
```

It's a pretty simple modification of a standard binary heap implementation. You just have to be careful to update the position *every time* you move an item.

You can also do this with node-based heaps like Pairing heap, Fibonacci heap, Skew heap, etc.

Comment: Could you specify in de indexed binary heap? The first option doesn't work for me because for the tree to be balanced I have to have all the elements, I want to, while inserting, keep things sorted and knowing the index of an element.

Comment: @seba An [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) is a self-balancing binary tree. It keeps the tree balanced as you insert and remove things. However, a skip list will likely perform better, and is not much more difficult to implement. Also, as I pointed out previously, a binary heap does not keep the list sorted.